# Kubernetes nginx Ingress reverse proxy on subpath with http_referer

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to use the networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress nginx to route and serve multiple services on different subpaths of a single domain using the same port?

The applications cannot be adjusted in any way to support this, but is expected to be using relative pathing when refering to other resources inside themselves.

### Findings:

I have found something that might do the trick using $http_referer, since the applications are React-based (possibly other SPA's).

```
if ($http_referer ~ "^https://[^/]+/subdir/") {
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://$http_host/subdir/$1 redirect;
}
```

But i cannot find out how to do this with the nginx Ingress in Kubernetes.. Any solutions or alternatives are welcome!

This is what the Ingress looks like at the moment. It successfully redirects the subpath to the server, but following calls goes to root path from the application. Thus the need for some $http_referer use i think..

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
  namespace: myapplication
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: test.mytestdomain.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /mysubpath(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
```

### Usage sample:

Application1 should be hosted under test.mytestdomain.com/app1/

Application2 should be hosted under test.mytestdomain.com/app2/

The applications should be able to act as if hosted on the root of the domain, and are expected to give the browser links such as: test.mytestdomain.com/styles.css, which should then end up inside the correct application that is making the request.